# How to make Angular material UI component (mat-checkbox, mat-radio-button) focus visible by tab navigation?

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button, accessibility, focus

I am implementing a11y and some Material UI components cannot be focused by tab navigation and don't show the focus-visible style. For example mat-radio-button, I can not using tab navigation to focus on input in theses elements.

This is my code:

**Typescript**

```
<mat-radio-button tabindex="0"></mat-radio-button>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
 &:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #DE190A;
  outline-offset: 3px;
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the tabindex=0 attribute to somewhere in the actual elements generated by the component, not on the component tag itself (unless it's correctly transmitted). Depending on how it has been built, it can be anything from very easy to very difficult.

Comment: Also make sure you're not trying to fix a problem that isn't a problem. You use a radio button in your example and that's actually an element that should **not** be tab focusable **individually**. When you have a group of radio buttons contained in a radio group, the group *as a whole* can receive TAB keyboard focus and the focus goes to the currently selected radio button. You then use the arrow keys to navigate to the other radio buttons. You should **not** be able to TAB to each radio button individually.

Comment: (continued) Now, having said that, Firefox is weird in that when a radio group is first displayed and nothing is selected, Firefox **does** let you TAB to each radio button individually. But once you select one of the radio buttons, then Firefox behaves "normally" and only lets you TAB to the group as a whole.  Chrome, Edge, and Safari don't have this initial problem. When I try the [`<mat-radio-button>` example on angular](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview), the TAB key works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is only a misunderstanding of how keyboard navigation should work.

**Radio buttons are not focused via <kbd>tab</kbd>**

Well, quite. A *radio button group* is what’s called a composite widget: only one element can be focussed via <kbd>tab</kbd>, afterwards the **arrow keys** allow selecting an option.

[Material UI’s Radio Button](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) supports that behaviour natively.

The ARIA role `radiogroup` is derived from the [composite role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#composite):

> Once the composite widget has focus, authors SHOULD provide a separate navigation mechanism for users to navigate to elements that are descendants or owned children of the composite element

Comment: Thanks, your answer is constructive, make me more understanding of radio button behavior. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Accessibility features in the Material CDK - focuskeymanager specifically: https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focuskeymanager

Material radio button styles are controlled by the theme: https://m2.material.io/components/radio-buttons/web#api

Comment: I tried but idk why it doesn't work in my case

Comment: Are you using Safari by any chance?

Comment: I am using Chrome (on macbook)

Comment: Did you add the styles path to your angular.json?
<https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#external-and-global-style-files>

Comment: Material radio buttons styles are controlled by the theme: <https://m2.material.io/components/radio-buttons/web#api>